# Could someone explain these pointer parameter questions?

Tags: c, pointers

```
{
    /* Prototype declaration */
    void printOne(int *);
    void printTwo(int *);
    void printThree(int *);

    /* Local definitions */
    int num[5] = {3, 4, 6, 2, 1};

    /* Statements */
    printOne(num);
    printTwo(num+2);
    printThree(&num[2]);
}

void printOne(int *x)
{
     printf("\n%d", x[2]);
}

void printTwo(int *x)
{
     printf("\n%d", x[2]);
}

void printThree(int *x)
{
   printf("\n%d", x[2]);
}
```

What would be printed from the preceding program block?

The answer is 6,1,1 respectively, but I am a little confused with printTwo and printThree. For printTwo, does num+2 actually mean the third index? And when passed in the third index, `x[2]` does what to it? And printThree is passing in the &address of index 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three of the functions take an `int*` as an argument. This is a pointer to an `int`, that is, the address of an `int` variable.

In the call `printOne(num)`, the argument `num` is the address of (i.e. points to) the start of the `num` array (i.e. `num[0]`, containing the value `3`).

In the call `printTwo(num+2)`, the argument `num+2` is the address of the third element in the array; that is, it points to the address of `num[2]`. The array element `num[2]` contains the value `6`.

In the call `printThree(&num[2])`, the argument `&num[2]` is another notation also referring to the address of the third element in the array (`6`).

In each of the three functions, the variable `x` is the function's local name for the passed pointer. The variable `x` can be regarded either as a pointer to an int, or as a pointer to the start of an array of ints.

So in `printOne(num)`, `x` contains the address of `num`, that is, the address of the memory location containing the value `3`.

In both `printTwo(num+2)`and `printThree(&num[2])`, `x` contains the address of `num[2]`, the memory location containing the value `6`.

In each function, the value of `x[2]` is printed. In each case, this is the third element of array `x` (which is not necessarily the array `num`).

So in `printOne(num)`, the first element of `x` is `3`, and the third element (the value printed) is `6`.

In `printTwo(num+2)`and `printThree(&num[2])`, the first element of `x` is `6`, and the third element (the value printed) is `1`.

Answer (score 1):

`printTwo()` takes a pointer to an `int`. You are feeding it `num + 2`.

`num` is (treated like) a pointer to the first element of the array. Pointer aritmetic on arrays guarantees that `num + 2` will point to the element of the array two positions after the first, provided there are enough elements in the array. You are allowed to go up to one position beyond the array bound and get consistent results, though you'd not be pointing to any significant value.

So, inside the function, `x` points to 6. Then you use array notation to print `*(x + 2)` which is the same thing as `x[2]` really. That means you're moving two positions further down, thereby pointing to the array position containing 1, and then dereferencing to get the value.

As for `printThree()`, it's the exact same function as the previous one. Moreover, you are passing `&num[2]` which means the very same thing as `num + 2`, provided the array is large enough.

Answer (score 0):

### About the questions:

- **printTwo()**, the `+` operator works on pointer, thus `num+2` point to the element that is 2 position after `num`, which point to `6`, then u call `x[2]`, that is another 2 position after, which is `1`.
- **printThree()**, `&` operator works on `num[2]`, thus it get pointer to `6`, then it's similar as in printTwo().

---

### The trick in the code:

- pointer increase/decrease in unit of element size,
- `[]` operator has higher priority than `&`